# How to open tag in vertical split?

Tags: vim, split, shortcut

I can move over a word in Vim and hit <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> and the tag opens in a horizontal split which is very handy, <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> will do the same for files (very useful to open headers e.g.). Now how can I do the whole magic with vertical splits rather than horizontal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if it exists. However, you can make your own binding:

```
nnoremap <C-W><C-V>f :exec "vert norm <C-V><C-W>f"<CR>
nnoremap <C-W><C-V>[ :exec "vert norm <C-V><C-W>["<CR>
```

This will bind <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> to be the vertical equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> (and similar for tags).

Answer (score 4):

This mapping doesn't exist, but you can make one:

```
nnoremap <c-w>F <c-w>vgf
nnoremap <c-w>[ <c-w>v<c-]>
```

FYI `vert` doesn't like to cooperate with `execute` or `normal`, so don't use them together. **If you don't need to evaluate something into the map, then you don't need** `:exe norm!`.

Comment: For me the operation is not complete, it opens a vertical split of the existing window and not of the definition, as if it is being "stopped" after the vertical split happens...

Comment: @Corel What happens when you try typing in `<c-w>v<c-]>` manually?